# Manually populate Azure database

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure

I have just hosted an MVC web app that had lots of data in the development database, but the production database is empty. I am very new to Azure and am wondering how to navigate to a page where I can populate tables manually, or what is most straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> what is most straightforward way to do this?

If you want to migrate your Local SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database, You could follow the azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database) to do that.

> Moving your SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database is as simple as creating an empty SQL database in Azure and then using the [Data Migration Assistant (DMA)](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=53595) to import the database into Azure.